# GA data is different from GA Dashbaord and GA API

Tags: java, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to fetch GA data from GA Java APis.When i fetch data for a particular URL its page views data and time spent on page data form API is different for same time range.

For one URL i got this difference.

This is query

```
{
dateRanges=[{
    endDate=2016-07-28,
    startDate=2016-07-28
}],
dimensionFilterClauses=[{
    filters=[{
        dimensionName=ga: pagePath,
        expressions=[/53433409.cms],
        operator=REGEXP
    }]
}],
dimensions=[{
    name=ga: pagePath
},
{
    name=ga: hostname
}],
metrics=[{
    alias=PageViews,
    expression=ga: pageviews
},
{
    alias=TimeOnPage,
    expression=ga: timeOnPage
}],
samplingLevel=LARGE,
viewId=123
}
```

Response

```
{
"reports": [{
    "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": ["ga:pagePath",
        "ga:hostname"],
        "metricHeader": {
            "metricHeaderEntries": [{
                "name": "PageViews",
                "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
                "name": "Time On Page",
                "type": "TIME"
            }]
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "isDataGolden": true,
        "maximums": [{
            "values": ["16996",
            "1360186.0"]
        }],
        "minimums": [{
            "values": ["76",
            "391.0"]
        }],
        "rowCount": 5,
        "rows": [{
            "dimensions": [" x.x.com/articleshow_comments/53433409.cms",
            " x.x.com"],
            "metrics": [{
                "values": ["76",
                "391.0"]
            }]
        },
        {
            "dimensions": [" x.x.com/life-style/home-garden/abc/amp_articleshow/53433409.cms",
            " x.x.com"],
            "metrics": [{
                "values": ["681",
                "14714.0"]
            }]
        },
        {
            "dimensions": [" x.x.com/life-style/home-garden/abc/articleshow/53433409.cms",
            " x.x.com"],
            "metrics": [{
                "values": ["88",
                "3228.0"]
            }]
        },
        {
            "dimensions": [" x.x.com/life-style/home-garden/abc/articleshow/53433409.cms",
            " x.x.com"],
            "metrics": [{
                "values": ["14361",
                "1272052.0"]
            }]
        },
        {
            "dimensions": ["m.x.x.com/life-style/home-garden/abc/articleshow/53433409.cms",
            "m.x.x.com"],
            "metrics": [{
                "values": ["16996",
                "1360186.0"]
            }]
        }],
        "samplesReadCounts": ["999997"],
        "samplingSpaceSizes": ["12608639"],
        "totals": [{
            "values": ["32202",
            "2650571.0"]
        }]
    }
}]
```

}

Java API :
PV : 32000
Time Spent total : 2642623

From dashboard
 PV : 31000
Time Spent total : 5397828

Time range given from 28 mid night to 29 mid night as GA takes absolute date always.

dateRanges=[{endDate=2016-07-28, startDate=2016-07-28}

Has anyone seen this kind of issue. I have included sampling level large but still it is not including all samples.
We have premium account.

Thanks
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: 99% of the time the answer to this is either: sampling (`containsSampledData`: are your results sampled?), filters mismatch, segment mismatch, other parameter mismatch, or data recency (`isDataGolden`: You are asking for yesterday's data but has processing finished?). There is not enough information in your question to deduce which the likely cause.

Comment: @Matt processing is done as pageviews were n ot increasing for that date range. I checked sampling as it is data fetch for one particluar page and it has page views 31000 which is less than sample size of 99999 so i think this should be fine. Coul you please explain what more info required.

Comment: After you included your actual response I can see         `"samplesReadCounts": ["999997"], "samplingSpaceSizes": ["12608639"],` your results are infact sampled. The sampling limits are not the same for the API and UI. As you are already querying for a single date range I would look for other ways to reduce the cardinality. Perhaps use content grouping, or query for an alternative metric `ga:avgTimeOnPage`.

Comment: @Matt i got it working as time spent on page is calculated by total time/ (pageViews-exits) . Please let me know if you find anything about sampling limits and reducing carnality. Many thanks for your help and i will wait for your response.