# GA API differences with UI

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using segments, I am building an app that lets user enter a URL and check different metrics for it.

I see some significant differences between reports pulled with the API and report generated in the UI. Maybe I am misunderstanding something about segments.

For example, I have a segment designed to show only users that went on a specific page.

[image]

which map to a small fraction of my users:

[image]

When looking at the user age brackets, I see small numbers scattered across all categories.

[image]

Now to run the equivalent report in the API, I am using the payload below.

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "#####",
      "dateRanges": [
        { "startDate": "2017-03-01",
          "endDate": "2017-04-27" }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {"expression": "ga:pageviews"},
        {"expression": "ga:sessions"},
        {"expression": "ga:users"}
      ],
      "segments": [
        {
          "dynamicSegment": {
            "name": "Users of /apath/ofinterest/",
            "userSegment": {
              "segmentFilters": [
                {
                  "simpleSegment": {
                    "orFiltersForSegment": {
                      "segmentFilterClauses": [
                        {
                          "dimensionFilter": {
                            "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                            "operator": "EXACT",
                            "expressions": [
                              "/apath/ofinterest/"
                            ]}}]}}}]}}}
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        { "name": "ga:userAgeBracket" },
        { "name": "ga:segment" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which yield completely different results:

[image]

Only 2 age brackets, and weirdly, the same number of users in each (I tried with different time frame with the same behaviour).

Any ideas on what could be wrong? Could it be something in the settings of the segment? Related to "Sessions/User Include"?

Or could this warning below that I see in the UI have different impact in the UI and the API?

[image]

According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653527/ga-data-is-different-from-ga-dashbaord-and-ga-api#comment64731306_38653527), it sounds like numbers might be calculated differently for the API and the UI. Is that still the case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is either of your reports sampled? With such a small segment (with respect to your 6 million users), I would have to guess that the data is sampled.

Comment: The report seems indeed sampled. I was not expecting to see the same numbers, just a fairly similar split of the numbers...

Comment: Proportionally your users are only 6% apart in your GA report, and are the same through the API. I would say thats fairly close, enough for sampling to effect.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear in the screenshot, but in the API, I see 248 (124+124) users, vs 475 in the UI. That is more than 6%.

Comment: Just to clarify: I was comparing the difference in users between 35-44 and 55-64.In the GA report there is a 6% difference in the user numbers, where as in the API report they are the same. In the API report, the numbers (248) is so low because it is not reporting on the other age brackets (18-24, 25-34, etc). Sampling in GA works by taking a random sample and extrapolating the values as per the sample. For example a transaction report with 25% sampling will only show 25% of the unique transaction ID's, but will give each of those id's a value of 4 transactions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If the chosen sample happened to only have users between 35-44 and 55-64 in equal proportion (which is, I guess, possible), I would have expected the extrapolation to still give a similar total number of users to the number seen the UI (~475, maybe 35-44 = 235 and 55-64 = 235).

Answer (score 0):

GA UI data is picked from the pre-aggregated tables.

**Pre-calculated data -- pre-aggregated tables**

These are the precalculated data that Google uses to speed up the UI. Google does not specify when this is done but it can be at any point of the time. These are known as pre-aggregated tables

---

So if you compare the numbers from GA UI to your GA API data, you will always see a discrepancy because the view might be aggregated at some early stages of the day, while your api data is fresh

Comment: But looking at past numbers (>2 days ago), the differences between precalculated data and API shouldn't really matter isn't it? Both set are calculated on known and available data at this stage.